# Remove duplicates from linked list using hashing

Tags: c++, linked-list

I try to remove duplicates from a linked list using hashing. Not with `unordered_map` but using a vector for tracking the occurrences. I run a simple test case and I get a result that I don't understand.
My code is :

```
class Solution {
   public:
         Node* removeDuplicates(Node *head) {
             vector<int> vec{10000 , 0};
             auto tmp = head;
             auto tmp2 = tmp;
             while (tmp) {
                 vec[tmp->data]++;
                 cout << "Data : " << tmp->data << " counter " << vec[tmp->data] << "\n";
                 if (vec[tmp->data] > 1) {                     
                     tmp2->next = tmp2->next->next;
                 }
                 tmp2 = tmp;
                 tmp = tmp->next;
             }
             return head;
         }
```

I tried the following test case
2 3 3 4 6. This are the data for the nodes in the linked list.

And the result I get is this.

```
Data : 2 counter 1
Data : 3 counter 1
Data : 3 counter 2
Data : 4 counter 1
Data : 6 counter 4114

2 3 4
```

The actual result should have been

```
Data : 2 counter 1
Data : 3 counter 1
Data : 3 counter 2
Data : 4 counter 1
Data : 6 counter 1

2 3 4 6
```

Comment: Dangerous design, though (even if fixed, see given answer). Is it guaranteed by any means that no data element will *ever* have a value >= 10000?

Comment: @Aconcagua I would use unordered_map but this is in an online platform and it does not allow to ad headears so i had to do this

Comment: Want to be on the safe side anyway? `if(tmp->data >= vec.size()) { vec.resize(...); }`. By which value? At least `tmp->data + 1`, of course. I personally like duplicating to avoid further re-allocations, maybe something like: `2*std::max(vec.size(), tmp->data)` – if using large numbers, you'd need to prevent overflow, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vector<int> vec{10000, 0};` creates a vector with two elements `10000` and `0`, using the constructor that takes an `std::initializer_list`:

```
vector(std::initializer_list<T> init, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

Most likely you need `vector<int> vec(10000, 0);`. This will create a vector of 10000 elements, initialized with `0`, using

```
vector(size_type count, const T& value, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

The standard [reads [over.match.list]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.list):

> When objects of non-aggregate class type `T` are list-initialized such that [dcl.init.list] specifies that overload resolution is performed according to the rules in this subclause, overload resolution selects the constructor in two phases:
>
> - **Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors ([dcl.init.list]) of the class `T` and the argument list consists of the initializer list as a single argument.**
> - If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class `T` and the argument list consists of the elements of the initializer list.

Comment: Haha, my favourit again – once more... This is the most obvious example (of quite a bunch of others) for why I consider uniform initialisation flawed. My recommendation: just don't use it! `vector<int> vec(1000, 0);` and `vector<int> vec({1000, 0});` are so much clearer to read (latter case explicitly *wanting* to create a vector with two elements...).